# How do I set width and positioning of an object with javascript from a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to create a button in javascript and make that button positioned below a canvas, the same width as the canvas, however, I don't seem to be able to set the top and width as a variable (the code is ignored). Here is my code: (problem lines commented)

```
var myButton = document.createElement('button');
myButton.style.position = 'absolute';
myButton.style.left = '0px';
myButton.style.top = canvasHeight; //
myButton.style.width = canvasWidth; //
myButton.style.height = '100px';
myButton.innerHTML = 'Restart!';
document.body.appendChild(myButton);
```

Note that the canvas is resizable, so I can't just type in a  px value.

Comment: Where do the variables come from? Did you check their value in the console? Do they perhaps contain a wrong format, e.g. "100" rather than "100px"?

Comment: oooooh thanks I made a silly mistake! I had the variables stored as numbers rather than units like you said! Could you submit that as an answer so I can close this question and give credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my comment in an answer:

Make sure you have the correct format in `canvasHeight` and `canvasWidth`, e.g. "100px" rather than just "100".